# Accessing Internet from VirtualBox in Fedora

Tags: virtualbox, fedora-13

What procedures are there in connecting to the Internet from inside the VirtualBox virtualized with the Fedora OS? I'm using Windows 7 OS from which I'm running this virtualization.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to configure your Virtual Machine to use "NAT Networking", as explained in the [VirtualBox User Documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#id367761)

> If all you want is to browse the Web, download files and view e-mail inside the guest, then this default mode should be sufficient for you, and you can safely skip the rest of this section. Please note that there are certain limitations when using Windows file sharing (see the section called “NAT limitations” for details).

And:

> A virtual machine with NAT enabled acts much like a real computer that connects to the Internet through a router

So, basically, using NAT mode and letting your virtualized Fedora OS determine its network settings automatically (by using DHCP), you should be set and your Fedora should be able to reach the outside world through the VirtualBox adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: NAT mode is certainly the easiest way - it usually 'just works'